# How do I find the span of this particular polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm kinda new with this and find hard to solve the problems related to LA although I can visually and conceptualize stuff easily. Please help me to find $\{(v_1, v_2, v_3) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid 5v_1 - 3v_2 + 2v_3 = 0\}$.

Comment: What you originally posted was only part of a question. The other part is, how do you want the subspace to be represented? The phrase, "All vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ satisfying $5v_1 - 3v_2 + 2v_3 = 0$" is already a perfectly good description of something. Presumably you are meant to convert it into a different description, but what else were you told about how it should be described?

Answer (score 2):

A vector $u=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$  which satisfies the condition $: 5v_1-3v_2+2v_3=0$ can be written as

$$u=(v_1,v_2,\frac{1}{2}(-5v_1+3v_2))$$
$$=v_1(1,0,-\frac{5}{2})+v_2(0,1,\frac{3}{2})$$

Put $ u_1=(1,0,-\frac{5}{2})$ and
$u_2=(0,1,\frac{3}{2})$.

$u_1$ and $u_2$ are independent so your space is span$(u_1,u_2)$.

Comment: What if there are 2 equations that the vector  u=(v1,v2,v3) satisfies? 
How do we check if its a vector space & then its span & linear independence?

Answer (score 0):

We want to solve the system represented by the following augmented matrix:
$$[5 \ -3 \ 2 \ | \ 0]$$
To get this into RREF form, divide the row by $5$:
$$[1 \ -\frac{3}{5} \ \frac{2}{5} \ | \ 0]$$
Now, the pivot variable is the first coordinate and the free variables are the second and third coordinate. From the second coordinate we get the solution $(\frac 3 5, 1, 0)$. From the third coordinate, we get the solution $(-\frac 2 5, 0, 1)$. Thus, we get that the answer is the span of these two vectors.

Comment: Note that [Salah Fatima's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078543/307483) is also correct, but this is a different way to get equivalent answers. The span of $u_1$ and $u_2$ in Salah Fatima's answer is the same as the span of $(\frac 3 5,1,0)$ and $(-\frac 2 5,0,1)$.